# PHP MYSQL : insert dont work with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I've this code for insert row in my table :

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO cours (id_region, id_type, nom, difficulte, duree1, duree2, remarque, nb_personne, note, publicateur)
VALUES(:region, :type, :nom, :level, :duree1, :duree2, :remarque, :nbPerso, :note, :publicateur)');

$rq = 'not yet';
$note = 5;
$prod = 'admin';

$req->bindParam(':region', $region);
$req->bindParam(':type', $type);
$req->bindParam(':nom', $name);
$req->bindParam(':level', $level);
$req->bindParam(':duree1', $temps1);
$req->bindParam(':duree2', $temps2);
$req->bindParam(':remarque', $rq);
$req->bindParam(':nbPerso', $nbPers);
$req->bindParam(':note', $note);
$req->bindParam(':publicateur', $prod);

$req->execute() or die('Problem insert '.mysql_error());
```

When I call the php page, I've `Problem insert` ,I cant's see the error in detail

before to call prepared statement I've add this code for tracing error :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', 'C:wamp/www/Cours/php/log_error_php.txt');
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

in php.ini all my variable for showing error is equals to 'on'

where is error in prepared statement ?

Comment: You're mixing PDO with ext/mysql.  They are incompatible.  To obtain PDO errors, call [`PDOStatement::errorInfo()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php) (or [`PDO::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) and catch the [exception](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php)).  See [Errors and error handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) for more information.

Comment: when i idd PDOStatement::eerorInfo() i've this : 
Fatal error: Non-static method PDOStatement::errorInfo() cannot be called statically

Comment: `PDOStatement::` means that the method is defined in the `PDOStatement` class.  You must invoke it on your `PDOStatement` object, which in this case is `$req`.  That is, `$req->errorInfo();`.

Comment: i've this error now :

Problem insert Array

Comment: If you had taken the time to *read* [the manual page to which I linked](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php), all of this would have been answered.  `PDOStatement::errorInfo()` returns an array.  I suppose you could invoke [`print_r()`](http://www.php.net/print_r) upon it to view its full content, if that's what you want to do.

Comment: i change it as exemple in manual, and the error is :
PDOStatement::errorInfo():Array( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1062 [2] => Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'publicateur')

when i refresh my table in phpmyadmin, i dont have a row, it'e empty

Comment: I resolve the proble by doing truncate in table cours. Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are mixing PDO with mysqli and the two are not able to work with each other.

Answer (score 0):

You are using mysql_error(), but you don't use mysql.

Try [errorInfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) instead (for PDO in your case) or if you want to use mysqli you can use [mysqli_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: i change it, and i obtein this message :

Problem insert Array